# UILabel KVO observing

Tags: uilabel, key-value-observing

I am going nuts, I looked everywhere on the web but I always found the same code for KVO observing. Yet my observeValueForKeyPath: is never called; this is the simple code I use to observe UILabel taximeterValue:

```
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self=[super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self){
                [taximeterValue addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"text" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew |
                                                               NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) context:NULL];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary*)change context:(void*)context {
if ([keyPath isEqual:@"text"]) {
    if (myBookingAlert) myBookingAlert.taximeterValue=self.taximeterValue;
    NSLog(@"the text changed");
    // put your logic here
}
// be sure to call the super implementation
// if the superclass implements it
[super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath
                     ofObject:object
                       change:change
                      context:context];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

A few possible explanations:

1. `taximeterValue` is nil.
2. Nothing is changing `taximeterValue.text`.
3. Something is changing `taximeterValue.text` in a non-KVO-compliant way.  Every change to `taximeterValue.text` must be done either by calling `[taximeterValue setText:]`, or surrounded by appropriate `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:` messages.

Comment: That is an outlet, so it may not be nil. Of course I changed it before posting this query. Also the change is done by setText. I did not employ the changeValueForKey functions, as I read they are not necessary.

Comment: An outlet can be nil.  In fact, the outlet is probably nil during `initWithCoder:`, because outlet connections created in a nib are set *after* `initWithCoder:` returns, and before `awakeFromNib` is called.  Try moving your `addObserver:…` call to `awakeFromNib`.

Comment: Read about [“The Object Loading Process” in the *Resource Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW19) for the full story.

Comment: Thanks, I moved the function there and I will see if that solves the issue.